# Remove both lines if column A values are repeated in next row

Tags: shell, text-processing, sed, awk, scripting

My input is like this:

```
pak_c35079_g1_i1|m.14890    Pfam  
pak_c20797_g1_i1|m.3458     ProDom  
pak_c20797_g1_i1|m.3458     Pfam  
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     TIGRFAM  
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     Pfam  
.  
.  
.
```

I want an output like this:

```
pak_c35079_g1_i1|m.14890    Pfam
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     TIGRFAM
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     Pfam
```

Meaning that if a value is repeated in next line (in column A), than delete both lines.

Comment: please clarify why the last two lines are included in your example output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {last=""; last_line=""} { if (last == $1) {} else {print last_line} last=$1; last_line = $0}' < file_to_proceed
```

I'm not an `awk` expert, you will have problems with last line...

Comment: my expected output would be like this: pak_c35079_g1_i1|m.14890    Pfam could you help again, applogizes for posting an incorrect output...,,!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sed '$!N;/^\([^ ]* \).*\n\1/d;P;D' <in >out
```

It won't handle *three* consecutive identical first fields - but that doesn't seem to be what you ask, anyway.

My output is a little different than your example output given your example input:

---

```
pak_c35079_g1_i1|m.14890    Pfam
```

---

The `sed` command above will not print the two lines:

```
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     TIGRFAM
pak_c28265_g1_i3|m.9595     Pfam
```

...because doing so seems to conflict with the thing you ask for, and so I can only wonder at it being included in your example output at all.

Comment: I am extremely sorry about that...,,!!!! My expected would be like this: pak_c35079_g1_i1|m.14890    Pfam